# What's the best method for skinning a horizontal scroll pane using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am currently using [jScrollHorizontalPane](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jscrollhorizontalpane) to scroll through the thumbnails [here](http://v2.revelinnewyork.com/people/kev-okane). It's a great plugin, but unfortunately, the browser has to be resized for the scrollbar to show up. I suppose this is a bug, but the support is lacking.

My question is should I keep trying to get this to work correctly, or is there a simpler, or more efficient jQuery based scrolling method out there?

Remember, I'm not creating a scrolling slideshow, rather just skinning the default scrollbar. Thoughts? Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just figured it out. The width of the inside element must be set **before** the jScrollHorizontalPane script starts. I had another script setting the width through the DOM, but it's too late at that point because jScrollHorizontalPane has already calculated its own width.

Using PHP now to set the width of the inside element server-side.